# Xcode not displaying full list of available simulators

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

In my other projects the simulator drop-down menu shows simulators for 5.0, 5.1, 6.0, etc. In one certain project I'm only given the options for 6.1, even though my deployment target is 5.0. What project setting would cause the list of simulators to not show some installed simulators?

Comment: Change development target to 5.0

Comment: On "project" settings, on the info tab, select "iOS deployment target". If you haven't changed your "target" settings, it will automatically inherit the "project" settings. If you've already changed your "target" settings, too, then you'll want to adjust it there, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked this in both, the project and the target ?